# Crash on loadNibNamed(_:owner:options:)

Tags: ios, swift, nib

I have a custom `UIView` implemented in `CustomView.swift`. I then try to instantiate a `CustomView` object in another class called `CustomClass.swift` via:
`NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(String(CustomView), owner: self, options: nil)`

And I get the following exception:

> *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7faceb60e300 of class 'CustomClass' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
>   Unrecognized selector -[CustomClass awakeAfterUsingCoder:]

Answer (score 17):

It turns out that the argument specified as `owner` in `loadNibNamed()` must inherit from `NSObject` since the owner is expected to respond to `awakeAfterUsingCoder:`, as the error message suggested. But I could not find such requirement on Apple's documentation.